# blueimp fileupload max upload files

Tags: jquery, symfony, file-upload

I'm using the [basic plugin version of blueimp fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) for the utilitary side (drag&drop, etc) of it and don't use any ajax but rather submit the files like a traditional form but I'm encountering issues :

- I can't select more than 4 files (Tested on IE & Chrome)
- Drag and dropping file from my windows explorer to the upload zone triggers the "add" event callback but not the "change" event callback so when I submit I get an array of files with only the key 0 that equals to null

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#message_files").fileupload({
        replaceFileInput : false,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
        //singleFileUploads: false,
        autoUpload: false,
        change: function(e, data){
            if(data.files.length>=5){
                return false;
            }
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
        },
        add: function(e, data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.files.length);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe it is the serverside upload limit

Comment: @johnSmith not really, it's the same file, being selected with the "popup" and then by dropping it in the zone